# Error occurred when a localspark session instance accessed by two application at same time. An error occurred while calling o2402.defaultParallelism

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

In my case two applications are simultaneously trying to access the same spark context. But at some cases I got this defaultParallelism error since spark context is stopped.

Error stack trace:

````
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2402.defaultParallelism.

: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

(No active SparkContext.)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism(SparkContext.scala:2359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**:
Stop the spark context before it application ends.

**Explanation**:

Let us consider two applications are trying to access the spark context(parallel process).

- Initially at t=0, Application 1 starts the spark context and process
  is ongoing
- At t=1 application 2 starts and it also uses the same
  spark context.
- At t=3, Application 1 completed and it kills the local
  spark context it creates.
- At t=4, Application 2 still running and it
  tries to access the killed spark context So It throws the above error and
  application terminated

**Solution**:
Don't kill the spark context before both the application complete.